# Transfer DBF file to EXCEL to PHP

Tags: php, excel, dbf

Is it possible to transfer a dbf file to excel and then transfer it again to php? Can someone give me ideas or links? So I can achieve this? Or can someone suggest to smoothly transfer the DBF file to PHP?

I'm trying to create a student portal and get some data from their enrollment system(Visual fox pro) like Class Schedules, Enrolled students, Class lists, Faculty list. My student portal don't have an enrollment system because they have already an enrollment.

Comment: As it stands, it's very hard to figure out what you're asking here. Please edit your question to include code you've tried so far. Try and make it as _narrow as possible._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.dbase.php manual good for all

if you want read and write DBF file you can download source code here
http://achmatim.net/2010/03/17/baca-tulis-file-dbf-dengan-php/